# Adjust colors based on known HSV of region in image (using ImageMagick or similar)

Tags: color-theory

This is a question about how to color correct an image using ImageMagick or similar.

We have an image with a CMYK swatch. The swatch was printed on non-glossy white card stock and we've measured the HSV of the Cyan (in real life) under pre-determined lighting conditions. We then include this swatch on the card stock in the foreground of other images we take. Because the other images all have different lighting conditions, we're not able to objectively identify the colors of the other objects in the image.

Is there a way, using ImageMagick or similar, to shift HSV values throughout the image, using Cyan as the base, so that the color or the other objects in the image reflect values similar to what they would have had, had they been shot in the same lighting conditions as the CMYK swatch?

In short, our goal is to be able to determine, with some accuracy, the HSV of, say, "Yellow" (which, without enough light can look orange or brown).

I've found a few articles that suggest techniques for doing similar things but nothing quite like what we're trying to do here.

Comment: One thought is to convert your image to HSL or HSV or HCL. Convert your calibrated cyan swatch to the same colorspace. Then find the difference in the 3 color channel values (H, S or C, L or V). Then convert the image to sRGB, use -modulate to shift the image the same about by that difference. Then convert the result back to CMYK (assuming your input was CMYK). Note that -modulate has values that range from 0 to 200 with 100 being no change. So you need to convert the H, S or C, and L or V values appropriately. H is the hard one, since it ranges from 0 to 360. If you need help, let me know.

Comment: CONTINUED: You could also just shift value by addition or multiplication in the H, S or C, L or V channels and convert back to your original colorspace. Do this after get the H, S or C, L or V, color differences or ratios from the two cyan regions.

Comment: Wow, great answers (but I can't mark this as answers since you wrote them as comments). This is all so new to me and it's going to take me a while to test these suggestions. If you can provide a concrete example, with a sample image and the code required, it would be extremely helpful. Thank you!

Comment: It would be better if you provided your actual image or a subsection of it with enough area around the color swatch that you can tell if it looks reasonable after processing. Making a fake one would be hard to tell if it worked adequately. If the image is proprietary, we can set up a dropbox to exchange. Let me know or provide your direct email.

Comment: CONTINUED: If the image is not proprietary and you cannot post the image here due to privileges, then you can post to some free hosting service and put the URL here in your post.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you put in a cyan card into your scene, why did you not put in a full standard color chart there instead. If you did, you might be interested in these links: http://im.snibgo.com/findcard.htm and http://im.snibgo.com/colchkcha.htm

Comment: Yes, the image is proprietary but the link you sent in the last comment is almost exactly what we're trying to do so thank you for that. We're using a CMYK color chart because that was the most efficient choice at the time (easy to implement, inexpensive). I'll go through those links and follow up if I have any additional questions. Thank you!

Comment: I have no additional questions. Are you able to turn your comment(s) into an answer so I can give you credit for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two trivial approaches using ImageMagick and Unix tools.

Input Image (from http://im.snibgo.com/dcrawwb.htm)

[image]

1) Get the reference cyan color from http://xritephoto.com/documents/literature/en/ColorData-1p_EN.pdf

```
cyan_ref="srgb(8,133,161)"

cyan_ref=`echo $cyan_ref | tr -cs "[0-9]*\n" " " | sed 's/^[ ]*//'`
echo "$cyan_ref"
8 133 161
```

Separate the r, g, and b values

```
cyan_ref_r=`echo $cyan_ref | cut -d\  -f1`
cyan_ref_g=`echo $cyan_ref | cut -d\  -f2`
cyan_ref_b=`echo $cyan_ref | cut -d\  -f3`
```

2) Crop a small rectangle from the image and get the average measured color for the cyan patch.

[image]

```
cyan_mea=`convert cyan_measure.png -scale 1x1! -format "[pixel:u.p{0,0}]" info:`

echo "cyan_mea=$cyan_mea"
srgb(2,147,187)

cyan_mea=`echo $cyan_mea | tr -cs "[0-9]*\n" " " | sed 's/^[ ]*//'`
echo "$cyan_mea"
2 147 187
```

Separate the r, g, and b values

```
cyan_mea_r=`echo $cyan_mea | cut -d\  -f1`
cyan_mea_g=`echo $cyan_mea | cut -d\  -f2`
cyan_mea_b=`echo $cyan_mea | cut -d\  -f3`
```

3) Compute the differences as percents (relative to 255)

```
red_pct=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:(cyan_ref_r-cyan_mea_r)/255]" info:`
green_pct=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:(cyan_ref_g-cyan_mea_g)/255]" info:`
blue_pct=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:(cyan_ref_b-cyan_mea_b)/255]" info:`
```

4) Convert the image:

```
convert ftc_typ_sm.jpg \
-channel r -evaluate add $red_pct% +channel \
-channel g -evaluate add $green_pct% +channel \
-channel b -evaluate add $blue_pct% +channel \
ftc_typ_sm_corrected_rgb.jpg
```

[image]

Now you have a corrected image and can measure any other color from the chart or image.

If your images are cmyk, then do the same for c, m, y, k or convert to RGB and do the above.

Alternately, you can do this in HCL colorspace:

1) Get the reference cyan color from http://xritephoto.com/documents/literature/en/ColorData-1p_EN.pdf 
and convert to HCL (or HSL or HSV etc).

```
cyan_ref="srgb(8,133,161)"
cyan_ref_hcl=`convert xc:"$cyan_ref" -colorspace HCL -format "%[pixel:u.p{0,0}]" info: | tr -cs "[0-9]*\n" " " | sed 's/^[ ]*//'`
echo "$cyan_ref_hcl"
191 60 39
```

Separate the h, c, l values

```
cyan_ref_h=`echo "$cyan_ref_hcl" | cut -d\  -f1`
cyan_ref_c=`echo "$cyan_ref_hcl" | cut -d\  -f2`
cyan_ref_l=`echo "$cyan_ref_hcl" | cut -d\  -f3`
```

2) Measure the cyan swatch and convert the average to HCL

```
cyan_mea=`convert cyan_measure.png -scale 1x1! -format "%[pixel:u.p{0,0}]" info:`
echo "$cyan_mea"
srgb(2,147,187)

cyan_mea_hcl=`convert xc:"$cyan_mea" -colorspace HCL -format "%[pixel:u.p{0,0}]" info: | tr -cs "[0-9]*\n" " " | sed 's/^[ ]*//'`
echo "$cyan_mea_hcl"
193 73 42
```

Separate the h, c, l values

```
cyan_mea_h=`echo "$cyan_mea_hcl" | cut -d\  -f1`
cyan_mea_c=`echo "$cyan_mea_hcl" | cut -d\  -f2`
cyan_mea_l=`echo "$cyan_mea_hcl" | cut -d\  -f3`
```

3) Compute the differences and change to values suitable for -modulate (see http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#modulate)

```
cyan_h_diff=$((cyan_ref_h-cyan_mea_h))
cyan_c_diff=$((cyan_ref_c-cyan_mea_c))
cyan_l_diff=$((cyan_ref_l-cyan_mea_l))
echo "cyan_h_diff=$cyan_h_diff; cyan_c_diff=$cyan_c_diff; cyan_l_diff=$cyan_l_diff;"
cyan_h_diff=-2; cyan_c_diff=-13; cyan_l_diff=-3;

modh=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:100+$cyan_h_diff*200/360]" info:`
modc=$((100+cyan_c_diff))
modl=$((100+cyan_l_diff))
echo "modh=$modh; modc=$modc; modl=$modl"
modh=98.8889; modc=87; modl=97
```

4) Process the image

```
convert ftc_typ_sm.jpg -define modulate:colorspace=HCL -modulate $modh,$modc,$modl ftc_typ_sm_corrected_hcl.jpg
```

[image]

For more accurate approaches:

1) Do the RGB method for all swatches and compute the average R, G, B differences.

2) Do the HCL method and compute the average H, C, L differences

3) Do same but compute a lookup table for each of the red, green and blue (or hue, chroma, lightness) channels from the pairs of input and output values from each color patch in the image and the reference table.